# Stack Overflow in Spanish?

Tags: feature-request, international-sites

Since we now have a [Portuguese version of Stack Overflow](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/), the question is whether you are planning to support other languages.

In particular, I'm interested in a Spanish version of the site.

Comment: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about the creation of new Stack Exchange sites, not Stack Overflow. It belongs on [Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Great news! [The “Stack Overflow in Spanish” Project is Underway!](http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/21519/the-stack-overflow-in-spanish-project-is-underway).

Comment: [Stack Overflow in Spanish is here](https://es.stackoverflow.com) (I asked for reopen to post it as an answer)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a [proposal for it on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/42810/stack-overflow-in-spanish), which is currently on hold:

> This launch is on hold while we add the international features needed to make it functional for this community. Dates will be announced when available.

Notably, they are currently [hiring a Community Manager who is Spanish bilingual](https://hire.jobvite.com/CompanyJobs/Careers.aspx?nl=1&k=Job&j=oNY1Yfwu&s=Careers_Site), which would be an absolute requirement before such a site could be created.

As far as *other* languages go, I'll quote their blog on the subject: [Can’t We All be Reasonable and Speak English?](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/02/cant-we-all-be-reasonable-and-speak-english/)

> To be clear, we *still* don't think there needs to be a Stack Overflow in every language.
> ...
>
> We’re really only considering launching sites in languages that:
>
> - Have large, strong communities of high-talent developers, where
> - A meaningful percent of them aren't comfortable enough to participate in an English-only community
>
> That probably limits the list of potential candidates to Mandarin, Japanese, Portuguese, Russian, Turkish, and Spanish.
> ...